# Ruby Mash using

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-grape

Im using Grape and can't understand why i can't alter params Mash.

```
  class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base  
  end
```

Following is working fine:

```
  post do
    Publisher.create!({
      name: params[:name],
      partner_id: @current_partner.id
    })
  end
```

and creates new record in my DB with `name` and `partner_id` provided

but i have many entries in `params` so i want to just add `partner_id` to them.

```
  post do
    p params
    params.partner_id = @current_partner.id
    p params
    Publisher.create!(params.require(:name, :partner_id))
  end
```

output:

```
#<Hashie::Mash name="myName">
#<Hashie::Mash name="myName" partner_id=1>
```

but it insert line in DB with `NULL` in `partner_id` column

Is it incorrect use?

Also i can't use just `params` in `update()` because of `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is it correct workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that not only `partner_id` is null, but `name` also. So doing `Publisher.create!(params.to_h)` was solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `params` in `update()`, this is a security feature in Rails called Strong Parameters; see https://blog.8thlight.com/will-warner/2014/04/05/strong-parameters-in-rails.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters for more information.

Regarding your first problem, I think your call to `require` should be to `permit` instead:

`Publisher.create!(params.permit(:name, :partner_id))`

But it depends on if your request parameter names are Rails-like, i.e. `publisher[name]`, or bare as in `name`. If you are doing Rails-like parameters, you will want:

`Publisher.create!(params.require(:publisher).permit(:name, :partner_id))`

Comment: I think the DB is ok because if i fall back to my first example (under the "Following is working fine") than it works fine again.

Comment: You are correct, after re-reading your question I realise you already have the column added to your table. I've updated my answer, apologies.

Comment: Updated my answer again, I think I've worked out the root cause of you problem now. That'll teach me to answer questions quickly.

Comment: `params.permit(:name, :partner_id)` change nothing. still `NULL` in `partner_id` column. `params.require(:publisher).permit(:name, :partner_id)` throws error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'permit' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry that my answer hasn't helped fully. I can't look into this any more right at the moment.